# problems sending email to SMTP with PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, debian, phpmailer

I get the following error log when trying to send a message through an Exchange server:

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 mail.borschow.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.1830 ready at Tue, 7 Apr 2009 21:56:53 -0400 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 mail.borschow.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.1830 ready at Tue, 7 Apr 2009 21:56:53 -0400 " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 220 mail.borschow.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.1830 ready at Tue, 7 Apr 2009 21:56:53 -0400 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-TURN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ETRN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-DSN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8bitmime " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-BINARYMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-VRFY " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-X-LINK2STATE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY 250-X-LINK2STATE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY 250-X-LINK2STATE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-XEXCH50 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY 250-X-LINK2STATE 250-XEXCH50 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY 250-X-LINK2STATE 250-XEXCH50 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY 250-X-LINK2STATE 250-XEXCH50 250 OK " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mail.borschow.com Hello [10.0.254.231] 250-TURN 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8bitmime 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-VRFY 250-X-LINK2STATE 250-XEXCH50 250 OK 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type. " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type. " 
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type. 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.0.0 Resetting " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.0.0 Resetting " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250 2.0.0 Resetting
```

### Notes

- I've tried with my assigned user/password, but the administrator said there's not even a need to use a user/password when sending.  So I also tried without it, with no success.
- I even tried with **smtp.gmail.com**

### UPDATE (4/16/2009)

ok, I found my problem.

I am using an SMTP server that permits sending messages without authentication.  Therefore I removed the login and password from my code.  But I forgot to set the "uses authentication" flag to false.  Now it's working.

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 3):

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type. " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type. " 
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type.
```

What authentication are you using. I think thats causing the issue. Post the code here so that we can help more.

Answer (score 2):

remember that Gmail needs SSL for connecting and also they don't use the standard SMTP port. If you are using an old version of phpMailer you need to make a kind of hack to put it working.

[Here there is a page that can help you](http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

TLS is needed for many SMTP servers these days.